# Turning off echo in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have recently put together a script for my hostapd ap.

```
#!/bin/bash
#DNS
sudo rc.d start dnsmasq
#Initial wifi interface configuration
sudo ifconfig wlan1 up 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0

su -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"

#ip forwarding
sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables --table nat --flush
sudo iptables --delete-chain
sudo iptables --table nat --delete-chain
sudo iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface wlan1 -j ACCEPT

#start hostapd
sudo hostapd /home/monte/hostapd-test.conf
```

It works fine, but relating back to my question; How can I turn off/stop `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`, as it keeps my CPU running, which is a little annoying.

Comment: echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward ?

Comment: Yo, seriously I did not think about that. Thanks a bunch man! I wish this was a comment so I could vote you up!

Comment: The title is a bit misleading, anyway, @Icarus3 you should answer that before I do :P

Comment: @mux, please go ahead and answer it. I am feeling lazy !! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Booleans under `/proc` can be enabled by writing a `1` to them, and disabled with `0`. So simply perform the same echo as is done in the script but with `0` instead.